# How to create concave shape of a UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, calayer

Is it possible to make a concave shape of the side of a view?

I managed to round the edges with border radius, but I wonder if it's possible to make other nice transformations.
Here is the example:

1)This is my progress so far:
[image]

2)This is how it should be:
[image]

Is it possible to make a view look this way programmatically?
If not, I guess I'll use a png image to achieve this, but it's always nicer to finish these sort of stuff through code

Comment: Yes you can. You just have to play with UIBezierPath/CGPath to do it. They have methods to draw "arcs".

Comment: @larme Why don't you post this comment as an answer, so I can accept it. UIBezierPath/CGPath is the right way to do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [BezierPath and masking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16773753/bezierpath-and-masking) I prefer to mark it as a duplicate with a question showing it's possible.

Comment: True, same thing...but people like myself are not aware of UIBezierPath at all and will not even search it, so you can post a link to that question in your answer, so it's easier for others to navigate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`UIBezierPath`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/index.html)/[`CGPath`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPath/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CGPathRef) to achieve this.

There is a [good documentation from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/BezierPaths/BezierPaths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH11-SW1) about drawing, giving you hints ont curves, lines, etc:

Once you created your shape:

```
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
[maskLayer setFrame:[viewToMask bounds]];
[maskLayer setPath:[theBezierPath CGPath]];
[viewToMask layer] setMask = layer;
```